# Build jquery callback into requestAnimationFrame function for intervals

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-callback, requestanimationframe

In my function I animate the movement of a div from left to right with `requestAnimationFrame`.

```
move_right =  function(object){
  movement_right_ID = requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    move_right(object)  
});
    $(object).css({
         left: "+=5"
     })
     get_boundary(object) //this is another function that gives me the div boundaries and returns object_left
     if(object_left > $(window).width()){
         cancelAnimationFrame(movement_right_ID);
         $(object).css({
             left: "-100%"
         })
     }
}
```

This function runs as I want, i.e. it moves the div smoothly from left to right and resets it to the left position.

My problem, however is that I want to run this whole animation several times:

when I use

```
setInterval(function(){
        move_right($("#div1"))
    }, 1000);
```

I have the problem that it runs unsync soon after it started. I suspect that this is due to the animation not being finished when it wants to run again.

I am looking for a callback-like solution here but would prefer not to switch to the `animation` method.

So how would I change code to run the function in 1000ms intervals always after it finished?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var winWidth=$(window).width();
var myBox=$('.box');
var toggler=$('.toggler');
toggler.on('click',toggle);
myBox.isMoving=false;
myBox.timeoutID=null;
requestAnimFrame(render);

function render(){
    requestAnimFrame(render);
    moveBox();
}

function moveBox(){
    if(myBox.isMoving){
        myBox.css({left:'+=5'});
        if(myBox[0].getBoundingClientRect().left>winWidth){
            myBox.isMoving=false;
            clearTimeout(myBox.timeoutID);
            myBox.timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){myBox.isMoving=true;},1000);
            myBox.css({left:0});
        }
    }
}

function toggle(){
    myBox.isMoving=!myBox.isMoving;
    if(!myBox.isMoving){clearTimeout(myBox.timeoutID);}
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #cc0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
<input class="toggler" type="button" value="Toggle" />
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I'll try and let you know.